# setRequestHeader not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

This code work well in IE 11:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        beforeSend: (xhr, settings) => { xhr.setRequestHeader('X-TOKEN', this.xToken); }
    }).done(function (data) {
        d.resolve(data);
    });
```

but in Chrome (37 and 39 Canary) it doesn't work. The X-Token header is not added.
Is there a bug in the browser, or am I missing something?

Comment: Previously I've used $.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
   'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
 }); to work globally on all AJAX - maybe it will help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks but I need it for a single call

Comment: I think the problem here is your use of an arrow function, which is [not yet supported in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2700).

Comment: This is typescript ;)

Comment: Have you verified the value of `this.xToken` inside the `beforeSend` function? That's probably not your problem, but it would help to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: In my test the code works in Chrome 36, 37 and 39 Canary.

Comment: The valuiethis.xToken is ok, i have tested with debugger.